# copy text between two semicolons and add it to the end of the line

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have text like this:

```
0;Anguilla;
0;Antarctica;
0;Antigua And Barbuda;
0;Argentina;
0;Armenia;
```

just like 300 Countries more...
I want to copy the Country Name between the two semicolons and add it to the end of the particular Line.

So it looks like this

```
0;Anguilla;Anguilla
0;Antarctica;Antarctica
0;Antigua And Barbuda;Antigua And Barbuda
0;Argentina;Argentina
0;Armenia;Armenia
```

I tried something like this

```
/;.*?;/
```

but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are near to the solution, all you need is a capturing group:

```
search:  ;(.*?);
replace: $0$1
```

Comment: Thanks! This works great. I also found a Solution

Search: \;(.*)\;
Replace: ;\1\;\1

Answer (score 1):

In Notepad++ you can do this with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>

Find What : `(0;(.+?);)`

Replace With : `\1\2`

Click <kbd>Replace all</kbd>. Make sure you have 'Regular Expression' Selected

[image]