# Deleting everything outside of regex in notepad++

Tags: php, regex, email, notepad++, extract

I have looked through multiple questions here and I have come close to getting an answer, however, some of them are doing the exact opposite of what I need them to do. This is actually a good sign though, as it shows that I am making some progress.
What I'm trying to do is to make a **massive** email list from a database that I found. Each line contains random text before and after the email addresses which I have no practical use for, and would like to get rid of so that I can have a clean email list.
Each line looks something like this: (I had to censor some of the information)

```
3e:visito****@hotmail.com:88.247.216.***:s*****1
```

Every line is pretty much exactly like this and I need a way of deleting everything before and after what the regex marks.

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26274048/extract-email-from-text-usin-notepad-and-regexp) question I found a regex that selects all of the emails perfectly.

```
\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}\b
```

Also, on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23409562/regex-notepad-copy-text-between-to-semicolons-and-add-it-to-the-end-of-the-lin) question I found something to put in the *Replace With* box in Notepad++ and it deletes the emails and leaves everything other than the emails behind. So, in an essence, I need something that does the exact opposite of this.

Also, there's approximately 10 million lines *(844MB Database)* to go through so it needs to be mostly automated and easy to do multiple times to save time.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like your data has ':' as a field separator. If that's the case this would be a perfect scenario for switching to SED. SED allows you to define field delimiters and then print/delete fields row by row.  I'm not wrapping this up in an answer because I'm pretty rusty on SED and don't have a code sample.  However it is the right tool for this job. Notepad++ will just slow you down.

Comment: In Notepad++, I'd do it in 2 steps: 1) `(?s)^.*?(YOUR_REGEX)[^\n]*` => `\1`, 2) remove what remains at the end manually. In PHP, why not just use `preg_match_all`?

Comment: @stribizhev I just tested that on a small portion of the list, and it worked PERFECTLY! Thank you very much!

Comment: I could write the answer if you posted a comment that is works for you.

Comment: @stribizhev Yes your answer was perfect. I've used it and have extracted over 5 million emails. Thank you very much.

Comment: I posted my answer, please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The technique that can help you is a two step one:

- at first, you need to place your regex inside `(?s)^.*?(YOUR_REGEX)[^\n]*` (type it into the *Find What* field), and use the `\1` (backreference to the text captured with your original pattern) in the *Replace With* field.
- then, remove the text you do not need at the end manually.

So, in your case, use

```
(?s)^.*?(\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}\b)[^\n]*
```

Optimizing it a bit (mind that `[A-Za-z0-9_]` can be replaced with `\w` here), you can use the following regex with `. matches newline` option ON:

```
^.*?(\b[\w.%+-]+@[\w.]+\.\pL{2,4}\b)[^\n]*
```

**Explanation**:

- `^` - start of line in Notepad++
- `.*?` - any characters, zero or more occurrences, as few as possible up to the first word boundary
- `(\b[\w.%+-]+@[\w.]+\.\pL{2,4}\b)` - your *matching* pattern inside a pair of unescaped parentheses so that a capture is stored in the buffer:

  - `\b` - word boundary
  - `[\w.%+-]+` - 1 or more word characters (letters, digits or an underscore)
  - `@` - a `@` symbol
  - `[\w.]+` - 1 or more word characters or `.`
  - `\.` - a single dot
  - `\pL{2,4}` - 2 to 4 letters
  - `\b` - trailing word boundary
- `[^\n]*` - 0 or more characters other than a newline

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comment by [@stribizhev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/stribizhev), I need to do this following:

1: Add the following regex in the *Find What* box:

```
(?s)^.*?(\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}\b)[^\n]*
```

2: Add the following to the *Replace With* box:

```
\1
```

And that's it! Thank you very much everyone!

Answer (score 0):

If your file is formatted and has separated by `:`, maybe this regex works better for you:

```
[^:]*:([^:]*):.*
```

and replace it with

```
\1
```

In this way, you can get benefits for your separators.

Check [Here](https://regex101.com/r/tL3gZ2/1)